# MEAN project login post action freezes when placing break point in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, debugging, mean

I've made a MEAN project that has an admin panel. To access this admin panel one must login. For the time being a s basic login screen is used with an email address and password field.
This used to work (the project was on hold for a few weeks), but now that I'm picking it up again, for some reason my api call doesn't seem to work anymore. The only thing I did was update node.js to the latest stable version (4.3.6).

**EDIT:**

I've updated my code with the help of a tutorial and now my requests work. 
However I still have the strange issue where the debugging doesn't work in Visual studio. 
I noticed that the moment I place a break point in visual studio at the beginning of a post function which has a console.log for example, everything just freezes. When there is no break point my function works like it should.

Is something special needed to make debugging work with a MEAN project in visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real solution for people that will face the same problem but it is one for my problem.

I've given up after weeks of trying. I had to ditch MEAN anyway due to no support by my customer.

I Reverted back to .NET for back-end. Kept angularjs though.